# Using LINQ to retrieve a subset of data

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to retrieve data from a `List<T>` for paging purposes. How can do this in LINQ:

```
private List<MyData> GetPagingData(int pageNumber)
{
    if (pageNumber == 1)
        return myData.Take(8);

    // What to do here?
}
```

This works for page one. It returns the top 8 records. How do I make this work for page 2, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the page number to start at 0:

```
private IEnumerable<MyData> GetPagingData(int pageNumber, int perPage)
{
     return myData.Skip(pageNumber * perPage).Take(perPage);
}
```

If you want the page number to start at 1:

```
private IEnumerable<MyData> GetPagingData(int pageNumber, int perPage)
{
     return myData.Skip((pageNumber-1) * perPage).Take(perPage);
}
```

Comment: This assumes pageNumber is zero based.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.Skip` and `.Take`:

```
private List<MyData> GetPagingData(int pageNumber)
{
    int itemsPerPage = 8;
    return myData.Skip(itemsPerPage * (pageNumber - 1)).Take(itemsPerPage).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This would work if pageNumber is zero-based (that should be pointed out).

Comment: Yes, changed code to be 1 based as per the questions example. Thank you for highlighting.

Comment: - This does not compile since you want to return a `List<MyData>` but you're returning an `IEnumerable<MyData>`.

Comment: Added .ToList() so that it matches the questions format. Thanks for pointing out @TimSchmelter (also, did you down vote it for that?).

Answer (score 0):

```
myData.Skip(pageSize * (pageNumber - 1)).Take(pageSize) //if first pageNumber = 1
```

basically you have to play with skip and take functions

Comment: You need parens around the `pageNumber - 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
myData.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * 8).Take(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<MyData> GetPagingData(int pageNumber, int itemsPerPage)
{
    //Don't subtract 1 if you are using 0-based pageNumbers.
    int skip = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage;

    return myData.Skip(skip).Take(itemsPerPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pageNumber starts from 1:` Also adding another parameter without breaking your code.

```
private List<MyData> GetPagingData(int pageNumber, int? itemsPerPage)
{
    itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage ?? 8;
    return myData.Skip(itemsPerPage * (pageNumber-1)).Take(itemsPerPage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in EF and L2S, you have to order the list, and then the `Skip` method

```
private List<MyData> GetPagingData(int pageNumber, int itemsPerPage)
{
    return myData.OrderBy(i => i.Something).Skip(pageNumber * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage);
}
```

with this code, your first page will be 0